# Cakephp call an component method inside a helper

Tags: php, cakephp, components, helper

I use Cakephp 2.1 and I need to call a component method which resides in a plugin, from a view helper:

The component is here:

> /app/Plugin/Abc/Controller/Component/AbcComponent.php

The helper is here:

> /app/View/Helper/SimpleHelper.php

I tried inside helper:

```
App::import('Component', 'Abc.Abc');
$this->Abc = new Abc(); or $this->Abc = new AbcComponent;
```

or

```
$this->Abc = $this->Components->load('Abc.Abc');
```

inside the controllers this component works with no problem.
I know this isn't recommended (MVC design etc.)  but if I don't use it this way I need to duplicate a lot of code. I need to make something like:

```
MyHelper extends Helper{
   $simpleVar = Component->get_data();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I use CakePHP 2.4

This is how I successfully call Component from a Helper:

```
App::uses('AclComponent', 'Controller/Component');
class MyHelper extends AppHelper {
    public function myFunction() {
        $collection = new ComponentCollection();
        $acl = new AclComponent($collection);
        // From here you can use AclComponent in $acl
        if ($acl->check($aro, $aco) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Passing data from CakePHP component to a helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562053/passing-data-from-cakephp-component-to-a-helper)

This seems to be a very nice way to handle this.

I tried working the way you are before, and, although it seems to be a nice immediate solution, in the long run, it is better to just work with the component and helper as 2 separate entities in your controller.

lee

Comment: This solution is good, but I need so call a component from the helper. Not a helper from the component.   So I need to make:   $varInsideHelper = Compoent->giveSomeData();

Comment: Hello, The point is you should not really be calling components from helpers. In fact, the way I did it before is no longer allowed in CakePHP. You might try ClassRegistry::init('ComponentName'); I'm not sure if this will work the way you need, but it  might.

Comment: If you think you need to call a component from a helper your software has a serious architecture problem and you should definitely re-think what you do and how you do it.

Comment: I don't think is like that, I have a component that decides that the current user is allowed to see a part of a page.  So it's more a view logic if the partial is loaded or not.  But the permission check must be made by the component.

Comment: I think the proper flow would be to load the component into your controller, and dump its results into a $this->set() to be used by the element. If this check needs to be site-wide, you can load the component in to your AppController in the BeforeRender() function.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and I will get back with the response

Answer (score 0):

You can put logic in trait and use this from component and helper, if your porpouse is to use the same business logic in different places, to avoid duplication code.

By example

the trait (file app/Lib/NameOfTrait.php  or app/PluginName/Lib/NameOfTrait.php)

```
trait NameOfTrait {

   public function theTraitFunc($a, $b) {
       // Code here
   }
 }
```

The Component:

```
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');
App::uses('NameOfTrait', 'PluginName.Lib');
class NameOfComponent extends Component {
use NameOfTrait;
private $member;
private $controller;

public function __construct(ComponentCollection $collection, $settings = array()) {
    parent::__construct($collection, $settings);
    $this->member = $settings['memberName'];
}    
 function startup(Controller $controller) {
    $this->controller = $controller;
}
/**
 * Wrap function call of trait function,
 * I think the function doesn't have the same name, 
 * I don't try this  but I think  is obvious, 
 * to avoid the function to call itself
 */
public function theTraitFuncWrap($a) {
    return $this->theTraitFunc($a, $this->member);        
 }
}
```

Do The same for the Helper.

I hope this help someone, bye :)