# how to read cookie in helper class in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am using cookie helper in cakephp and i am using following code for accessing the value of cookie variable

```
$this->Cookie->write('testvar','testvalue');
```

I have made a helper class when i try to get the value of this cookie variable vid a following

```
$this->Cookie->read('testvar');
```

It produces an error(Call to a member function read() on a non-object).
Is there any other method by which i can access the cookie variable in helper.Although i can try the $_Cookie (server variable).

Comment: http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/309-there-should-be-a-cookie-helper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your helper should looks like:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
class MyCookieHelper extends AppHelper 
{
         public function writeCookie($name, $value = null) 
         {
               return CakeSession::write($name, $value);
         }
         public function readCookie($name)
         {
               return CakeSession::read($name);
         }
}
```

You can use it in your view like:

```
$this->MyCookie->readCookie($cookie_var_name);
```

Don't forget to include `MyCookie` helper in your controller;

```
public $components = array('MyCookie');
```

Comment: It Produces an error 
Call to a member function getController() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/CookieComponent.php on line 176

Answer (score -1):

You have to follow these steps :

In controller class you have to put this line or you can put in APP controller if you have to use this in multiple controllers :

```
public $components = array('Cookie');
```

and in action/function you can use this :

```
$this->Cookie->write('User.name', 'Larry');
echo $this->Cookie->read('User.name');
```

Comment: I can get the cookie value in controller class and in all its function.My question is how can i get the value in helper class.

Comment: Check out this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562053/passing-data-from-cakephp-component-to-a-helper

Comment: Cake follows the rules of Model-View-Controller separation, and since Components belong to the Controller tier, and
Helpers belong to the View tier, we don't mix the two.

What you can do is use the Component to pass data to the View through the Controller.You can then handle that data appropriately using your Helper. And your given link also suggest the same thing. From controller you can get the data and set it to the view and in view you can pass that variable as parameter for helper function.

Comment: Dear friend, I know this very well But you didn't read the question clearly.I asked that is there any method by which i can get the value of the cookie in helper and according to you,there is not any method.But we need lot of times,component and controller function on helper files.

Comment: The simple reason is cookie component hasn't helper class as other component has like session has session helper.If there is cookier helper exist we can access the function of that cookie class

Comment: That's right, that is the system which is followed by MVC architecture