# how to use public variable in helper file of cakephp

Tags: cakephp, controller, cakephp-2.0, helper

I have created a helper in cakephp and defined a global variable in AppController.php file.

AppController.php

```
public $testVar = null;
```

I want to use this variable in my helper file. How can do this?

Comment: I am not talking about the Auth component.

Comment: Isn't it same question as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562053/passing-data-from-cakephp-component-to-a-helper)? In Helper, you can use `$this->_View->getVar('testVar')`, after you `set()` it in controller

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that variable in a helper but you can either

1. In AppController, put the variable in the session: `Session::write('currentUser', $this->currentUser`). You can then access it in the Helper using the SessionHelper: `$this->Session->read('currentUser')`
2. Pass the variable to the view using set : `$this->set('currentUser', $this->currentUser)`. You can then access the `$currentUser` variable in the view and pass it to your helper as a parameter.

As an aside, if it is the ID of the logged in user you need and you're using the Auth component, you can find all the user information in the session already. You can access it in your helper as follows: `$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass around an extra variable.
Directly access AuthComponent statically:

```
echo AuthComponent::user('username');
```

etc.

Note: This is also notice-free as it checks on the existence first (which you would need to manually assert with using arrays here.

Comment: PS: if that is still too much to type, you can use sth like [Auth](https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Lib/Auth.php) to cut it down to `Auth::user()`.