# Pass variable from controller to layout in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

My variable `loggedIn` is defined in my `AppController`  in the `beforeFilter()` function, as follows:

```
function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller'=> 'questions', 'action' => 'home');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller'=> 'questions', 'action' => 'home');
        $this->Auth->allow('signup', 'confirm', 'home', 'show');
        $this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';
        $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.confirmed' => '1');
        $this->set('loggedIn', $this->Auth->user('id'));
    }
```

In my layout, I am testing the value of the `loggedIn` variable using the following:

```
<?php if($loggedIn): ?>
```

When I run the application I get this error:

```
Undefined variable: loggedIn [APP\View\Layouts\default.ctp
```

Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use `$this->Auth->user('id')` in your view!

Comment: you should also add `parent::beforeFilter()` inside the function. (Not that it would change much)

Comment: @GilbertoRamos No, that's not possible, `Auth` is a component, not a view helper. As of CakePHP 2 it's possible to use [**`AuthComponent:user()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user) though.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230330/how-to-use-public-variable-in-helper-file-of-cakephp/21232367

Comment: @ndm you are right! Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way to do this.

In your AppController:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->set('loggedIn', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
}
```

Or, if you need to access the loggedIn var in your controllers and your views:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $loggedIn = $this->Auth->loggedIn();
    $this->set('loggedIn', $loggedIn);
}
```

Why is this in beforeFilter()? So that the variable is accessible before preparing the page. This returns a Boolean, perfect for deciding if a user is logged in or not, so evaluate it as:

```
<?php if($logged_in===true): ?>
```

If you do still need the user ID or other user attributes, then use this in your view:

```
$id = $this->Auth->user('id');
```

[As on the bottom of this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html)

You wouldn't set individual attributes in beforeFilter if they can already be accessed in your view - you want to keep controllers as skinny as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter(); 
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller'=> 'questions', 'action' => 'home');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller'=> 'questions', 'action' => 'home');
        $this->Auth->allow('signup', 'confirm', 'home', 'show');
        $this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';
        $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.confirmed' => '1');
        $this->set('loggedIn', $this->Auth->user('id'));
    }
```

Change you beforeFilter function add line  `parent::beforeFilter();`, after that in layout file you can use `<?php if($loggedIn): ?>`

Comment: are you sure this is the fix? I am able to send variables to the view even without `parent::beforeFilter()`

Comment: the scenario is the code is not coming to beforeFilter function, I have faced this problem long time ago and this trick works, well your point is valid I am also able to send variables to the view file  without parent::beforeFilter()

Comment: It does not work with parent::beforeFilter()    ,  I set the variable in the usercontroller view ,   $this->set('loggedIn', $this->Auth->user('id'));  and it works but I still not understand why the variable was unknown in the previous code.  Any idea?

Comment: Does the `beforeFilter` function from `UserController` have `parent::beforeFilter`?

Comment: if you are on `/users/*` and your `userscontroller - beforefilter` (if it exists) function does not include `parent::beforefilter`, then the variable is not sent to the view